# Can't connect to PostgreSQL with QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgresql, error

I can create a connection to the database in QGIS and the test connection is successful. However when I actually connect to the database to export shapefiles I get the following error:

`the connection is failed, check the configuration.`

Comment: can you import the vector to qgis layout?

Comment: Do you see any error/ more information in Postgresql's logs?

Comment: Yes I can Import vector to  qgis layout.

Comment: I'm new (2 days) on Postgresql, but i can connect without problems the database with pgAdimin III. I have edit the pg_hba.conf and put this line: host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5.

Comment: If I test connection I get this:Conexão com PG:dbname='Teste_03' host='localhost' port='5432' user='postgres' password='pp2198'  foi completada           If I try to connect I get this get This:PG:dbname='Teste_03' host='localhost' port='5432' user='postgres' password='pp2198' não é uma fonte de dados reconhecida